# Errors while using itext

Tags: java, itext

I am getting 2 errors in this code -

1. The method setWidthPercentage(int) is undefined for the type table.
2. The method add(IBlockElement) in the type Cell is not applicable for the arguments (String).

I am using the following jars - 
io-7.1.4,
kernel-7.1.4,
layout-7.1.4,
svg-7.1.4,
slf4j-api-1.7.13,
styled-xml-parser-7.1.4

I am trying the example [ColspanRowspan](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-colspan-and-rowspan#2189-colspanrowspan.java)  which is given on Itext Website.

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;

import java.io.File;

public class ColspanRowspan {
    public static final String DEST = "./target/test/resources/sandbox/tables/simple_row_colspan.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File(DEST);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        new ColspanRowspan().manipulatePdf(DEST);
    }


    protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
        Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

        Table table = new Table(new float[]{1, 2, 2, 2, 1});
        table.setWidthPercent(100);

        Cell cell;
        cell = new Cell(2, 1).add("S/N");
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell = new Cell(1, 3).add("Name");
        table.addCell(cell);
        cell = new Cell(2, 1);
                cell.add("Age");
        table.addCell(cell);
        table.addCell("SURNAME");
        table.addCell("FIRST NAME");
        table.addCell("MIDDLE NAME");
        table.addCell("1");
        table.addCell("James");
        table.addCell("Fish");
        table.addCell("Stone");
        table.addCell("17");
        doc.add(table);

        doc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you aren't using **itext API's** correctly in your class. Below are the remedies for your errors:-

1. Method name itself is incorrect. In fact, there is no method with this name in Table class.  It's `Table.setWidth(UnitValue width)` which "**Sets the full width of the table**".

--> Reference:- [com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.1/com/itextpdf/layout/element/class-use/Table.html)

2. String type isn't supposed to be passed as an argument in your scenario for `add(IBlockElement)` method. Rather than you should use this `Cell.add(IBlockElement element)` looking properly for your requirement which "**Adds any block element to the cell's contents**".

--> Reference:- [com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.2/com/itextpdf/layout/element/class-use/Cell.html)

Comment: I am trying the example [ColumnWidthExample] which is given on Itext Website.

Comment: Would you please share the link so that I can check the same?

Comment: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/clone-colspan-and-rowspan#2189-colspanrowspan.java

Comment: Probably, you're getting mixed with all those classes on the webpage. Because if we go by your class name, there are many packages which haven't been imported. Additionally, you haven't included the annotation which is there in ColspanRowspan class. Please do re-check your code.

Comment: Actually there used to be separate `*Width` and `*WidthPercentage` float properties in several classes of early iText 7.0.x versions. These property pairs have each been replaced with a single `*Width` property of type `UnitValue` in later 7.0.x versions.